# jssor nested thumbnail navigator

Tags: slider, jssor

I a bit new to all of it.  HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  I need to setup a utility that will create a web page to display the artifacts for failed GUI tests.  Mainly the passing image, the failing image and the diff.

I came across jssor slider code and after looking at all of the examples what I want is a combination of the nested-slider and the list-slider.  Multiple verification points can fail for the test so I use the list control on the right listing all of the verification points that failed for the test.  What I want is when the user selects one of those the slider shows the pass image for that VP and on the bottom there is another thumbnail navigator that shows the 3, Pass, Fail, Diff.  And they can select from those to navigate between them.

I was able to get the right side list of VPs to work but I'm not sure how to nest another thumbnail navigator at the bottom.  I'm stepping through with the debugger to try and make some sense of it but any help would be much appreciated.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
-E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested slider is a main slider with some child sliders.

Each child slider is the same as a standalone slider.

You can add thumbnail navigator to any child slider.